# Probability Situation

Tags: probability, statistics

> A well known medical research organization conducted a study on a certain brand of test strips to see if a person has a certain disease. They found that $32\%$ of the people using the test strips actually have the disease. When a person with the disease uses these strips it correctly indicates that they have the disease $97\%$ of the time. A person who does not have the disease gets a correct reading $88\%$ of the time. Find $P(\text{has disease}\ \mid \text{tests positive for it})$

My attempt is as follows.
Using Bayes' Rule: $$P(\text{has disease}\ \mid \text{tests positive})=\frac{P(\text{has disease } \cap\text{test positive})}{P(\text{tests positive})}$$ We know the value of the numerator to be $0.97$ from the info in the passage. But how do we find the value of the denominator from the information given.

Comment: Are you sure about the numerator? For the denominator, $97\%\times 32\%+12\%\times 68\%$ - why?

Comment: 0.97 is not correct for the numerator. Rethink it.

Comment: Hint. Try working this out by imagining a population of 1000 users, 320 of whom will have the disease. That's equivalent to but easier to undersand than using Bayes' Rule. See http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/04/25/chances-are/ Search this site for "false positive" for answers to question like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $10,000$ people are tested (to avoid decimals)

Of these, $32\%$ or $3200$ have the disease, of which $97\%$ or $3104$ test positive

$6800$ don't have the disease, of which $12\%$ or $816$ test positive

Thus P(have the disease | test positive) $= \dfrac{3104}{3104+816}$

Answer (score 2):

Define $R$ to be the event of a positive test result, $R^c$ to be the event of a negative test result, $D$ to be the event that the person is diseased, $D^c$ to be the event that the person is not diseased.

We are given that $P(R|D)=0.97$ and $P(R^c|D^c)=0.88$, i.e. when a person does have the disease, the test result is positive, and when he doesn't, the result is negative. Notice that if the person is diseased, there is a 100% chance that the test result is either positive or negative (we assume that there is no other possible test result, or the problem cannot be solved). So we can infer that $P(R^c|D)=0.03=1-P(R|D)$, and $P(R|D^c)=0.12=1-P(R^c|D^c)$.

If we knew for certain if the person was diseased, we could say the probability that the test is positive is 0.97 (or not diseased, then 0.12). Since we don't know which state he's in, we assign a weighted probability by the rule $P(R)=P(R|D)*P(D)+P(R|D^c)*P(D^c)$.

Also note that Bayes' rule gives $P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.